# Connection to mongo db database using mongoose on a AmazonEC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I have been experiencing a lot of troubles trying to connect my node js server to my mongo database on my EC2 instance.

I use docker.

I have a container for mongo. I have followed this procedure : http://pierrepironin.fr/docker-et-mongodb/

I am able to connect to it via docker exec and I can do everything on my databases.

What I didn't manage to do is to connect to it in my node js app. I use mongoose and here this the code I use to connect to mongo :

```
exports.mongoConnection = function(mongo_url){
mongoose.connect(mongo_url); 
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
    logger.info('Mongoose default connection open to ' + mongo_url);
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
    logger.info('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
    logger.info("DB PATH : " + mongo_url);
}); 

// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {  
    logger.info('Mongoose default connection disconnected'); 
});

// If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection 
process.on('SIGINT', function() {  
    mongoose.connection.close(function () { 
    logger.info('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination'); 
    process.exit(0); 
  }); 
}); 
};
```

I have tried with several different urls but no one worked and I got errors like this one every time :

```
Mongoose default connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017
```

Here are some urls I tried but did not work :

```
"mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
"mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/test"
```

I also tried with user - password that I have created for one of my database.

```
"mongodb://my-user:my-password@0.0.0.0.0:27017/my-database"
```

I have also tried replacing 0.0.0.0 by my EC2 instance IP.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong here ? 
How can I connect to my mongo ? With which URL ?

Thanks you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your instance's firewall is blocking the incoming requests. In order to connect to your database, you will need to enter the correct IP address of the instance (Public IP) and ensure that the ports are open - in AWS this is under "Security Groups" and "Inbound"

`0.0.0.0` in the docs you have read is used as the address a server "listens" to, the 0.0.0.0 means it's "open to the world", which is usually not ideal and you'll want to change it later on in your `mongod.conf`

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Could you mark my answer as "correct"?